# I am struggling with Generics in Java Stream

Tags: java, generics, junit, java-8, java-stream

I know how to utilize intermediate and terminal function with streams, and many other basic things. 
but the task I have been given is confusing for me to implement. I have been struggling for last 36 hours non-stop.
my assignment is as follow:

> Implement one static method in a functional way, that takes a `List<T>`, filters it, orders it, returns only a certain amount of values and skips a certain amount of values and applies a mapping function to it. The returnvalue shall be a `List<R>`. T and R are unspecified generic types. All needed values shall be parameters. The limit and offset shall be optional.
>   Test your method using JUnit.

so far I could only manage to write the code and I am stuck with first step filter. confusion is, if I don't know type of list how can I filter it.

```
public class GeneralMethods<T,R> {

    private List<T> recList;
    private List<R> retList;

    public void manipulateList(){
        retList = recList.stream().filter(s -> s.)
    }
}
```

This is my assignment I have struggled alot, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Pass a `Predicate<T>` to your `manipulateList`, and use it to filter the input list.

Comment: Well, for starters, you are supposed to create a *static* method. Instead you created a state-based, non-static method. And there are no parameters. I suggest you write the correct signature, and the rest will be easier.

Comment: Besides your confusion about `static` methods, it seems your are struggling to understand that you don’t have to write a filter function. The caller of your method will. You only have to accept an appropriate `Predicate` parameter and pass it down to the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Your one liner should look something like

```
public class GeneralMethods<T,R> {

    public List<R> manipulateList(List<T> recList,
                                   Predicate<T> filterPredicate,
                                   Comparator<T> comparatorT,
                                   Function<T,R> mapTtoR,
                                   long ... limitAndOffset){

        return recList.stream()
                      .filter(filterPredicate)
                      .sorted(comparatorT)
                      .skip(limitAndOffset.length > 1 ? limitAndOffset[1] : 0)
                      .limit(limitAndOffset.length > 0 ? limitAndOffset[0] : Long.MAX_VALUE)
                      .map(mapTtoR)
                      .collect(toList());
    }

}
```

Then on the JUnit you must provide implementations of filterPredicate, comparatorT, and mapTtoR parameters.

Comment: You noticed the requirement to create a `static` method? Besides, you are offering a method that can take almost any number of trailing `int` arguments. I bet, no teacher will like that.

Comment: Yeah, an even more Java 8 functional approach would be public static <T,R> List<R> manipulateList(List<T> recList, Predicate<T> filterPredicate, Comparator<T> comparatorT, Function<T,R> mapTtoR, Optional<Long> limit, Optional<Long> offset){
 return recList.stream().filter(filterPredicate).sorted(comparatorT).skip(offset.orElse(0l)).limit(limit.orElse(Long.MAX_VALUE)).map(mapTtoR).collect(toList());
}

Comment: Put it into your answer; you know, you can [edit] it.

Comment: You can use [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3Lu09H7E) if you'd want to copy paste the formatted code.

Comment: Thanks Sergio Montoro, I got pretty good Idea on from your code. :)